How do I put a linker option in Compiler Explorer?
In Compiler Explorer I'm trying to compile something with MSVC, and I'm trying to have the address sanitizer throw an error, and in the output is says to:

warning C5072: ASAN enabled without debug information emission. Enable
debug info for better ASAN error reporting

How do I place a linker flag instead of a compiler flag? I have placed /fsanitize=address but it says I should set /DEBUG for the linker flag.

/fsanitize=address /Zi - live - https://godbolt.org/z/oadWhcYbh  see Debug Information Format

@RichardCritten OK, now I can ask my next question, why does Clang and GCC pick up the error and MSVC doesn't.

@RichardCritten write an answer.
